# Bootstrap tabs move when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I seem to have encountered a weird problem with my website. When I am on the home page and then click one of the tabs, it works as it should. As soon as I try to click from one of the other tabs to another tab (in my example, from News to Beats, from Beats to News, from News to Home and from Beats to Home) the content of the tab moves/shifts for a second and then switches. It never used to do this and it seemed to just start doing it all of the sudden. I was just wondering if anyone else has encountered this problem or if anyone knows of a solution. Here is the link to my website:

http://gscobeats.com/

Just to clarify, what I'm talking about is when you go on my site and let the whole thing load and click one of the tabs, the page does a fading transition effect then the page you selected appears. If you click from Home to any of the tabs it works fine. But if you are selected on one of the other tabs and you try to click a different tab, the page does this weird shrinking thing right before the transition starts. I was just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this

G-SCO

Comment: Using chrome, it's working fine. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I use chrome as well. I tried safari on my iPhone and it did the same thing. Maybe I didn't explain my problem properly. What I'm talking about is when you go on my site and let the whole thing load and click one of the tabs, the page does a fading transition effect then the page you selected appears. If you click from Home to any of the tabs it works fine. But if you are selected on one of the other tabs and you try to click a different tab, the page does this weird shrinking thing right before the transition starts. I was just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that in your tab content you are using `span12` elements without a container `.row` or `.row-fluid` element (which is an essential part of bootstrap's grid system), specifically you need that container because it provides a clearfix for the floated `span` elements, but if you wish not to change your markup you can add this to your CSS:

```
.tab-pane:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the border you're removing from the active item. Instead, set its color to transparent. You could also fiddle with padding to accommodate the line-height change.

```
.nav-tabs > .active > a {border: 1px solid transparent;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That was actually very helpful but maybe I didn't explain my problem properly. What I'm talking about is when you go on my site and let the whole thing load and click one of the tabs, the page does a fading transition effect then the page you selected appears. If you click from Home to any of the tabs it works fine. But if you are selected on one of the other tabs and you try to click a different tab, the page does this weird shrinking thing right before the transition starts. I was just wondering if anyone knew how to fix this